# Replicate and save on a model recieved by hasManyThrough relation does not work

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relationship

I'm asking for your advice on a somehow strange issue in Laravel. I have a database schema that looks like this:

- project

  - id
- tasks

  - id
  - project_id
- comments

  - id
  - task_id

I'm fetching a collection of comments from the database through a hasManyThrough relation on projects. The relation looks like this:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Comment', 'App\Models\Task');
}
```

This works fine. But if I replicate a comment and save it like this, it fails:

```
// fetch comments on project through a hasManyThrough relation
$comments = $project->comments()->get();

foreach($comments as $comment) {
  // this works:
  $comment->save();

  // this does not work:
  $replicatedComment = $comment->replicate();
  $replicatedComment->save();
}
```

Saving the replicated comment fails with the following error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project_id' in 'field list'

Somehow eloquent magically adds an additional attribute `project_id` to all models which is not handled right when calling replicate().

I can easily work around this by just unsetting the project_id before saving the replicated comment but this should not be the right way to do it. Can anyone reproduce this behaviour and is this a wanted behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your advice
Clemens

Comment: Evaluate the below two cases - 1. Put dd($comment) inside foreach and copy the result in text editor 2. put dd ($replicatedComment) before save() and copy the result in text editor. Now compare the data, check if they are same.

Comment: have you checked the value of `$replicatedComment` ? it is replicating the whole relationship thing.

Comment: @KeshariNandan I checked your suggestion. The objects are mostly the same. But one important thing differs: the values in the protected `original` attribute are not present in the replicated model. My assumption is, that calling save() on the original model works, because it has no changes that need to be saved to the database so the sql update query is just empty and there is nothing that can fail. On the replicated model the sql insert statement which is executed on save() is not empty so it fails if there is an attribute like project_id which has no coresponding column.

Comment: @Demonyowh true but replicating a hasManyThrough doesn't makes sence in my eyes. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and it will solve your problem -

```
$comments = $project->comments()->get();
foreach($comments as $comment) {
  $replicatedComment = $comment->replicate();
  $replicatedComment->project_id = $project->id;
  $replicatedComment->save();
}
```